# Node inspector doesn't work with Node 6.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I've updated my project to Node 6.0.0 from 4.2.2.

I figured out node-inspector won't work and causes "Internal error: illegal access" in console log after some time (it differs for every new debug session).

[image]

When I switched back to 4.2.2 everything works properly.

How to configure node-inspector to make it work with Node 6.0.0?

Comment: Good for you. What's your question?

Comment: Go file a bug / wait for an update.

Comment: With node-inspector.

Comment: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/864 has been opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Node 6.2.1 has been released and is supposed to fix this issue."](http://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/864)

Upgrade to node 6.2.1 and that should resolve the issue for you.